# angularjs ng-controller doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to work with AngularJS, and my "ng-controller" doesn't work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/angular.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app>
      <h1>Add user</h1>
      <form action="addUser" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="pseudo" placeholder="pseudo">
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password">
        <input type="submit" value="envoyer">
      </form>
      {{1 + 2}}
      <div ng-controller="myController">
      {{ name }}
    </div>
    <a href="./remove">supression</a>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function myController($scope){
        alert("test");
        $scope.name = 'toto';
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

When I'm trying this in Chrome, `{{1+2}}` is correctly replaced by '3', but `{{name}}` is not. I expected 'toto'.

I'm also trying to display an alert on click event, and it doesn't work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var myApp = angular.module('MyApp', []);
  myApp.controller('myController', ["$scope",function($scope){
    $scope.name = 'toto';
    $scope.onMyButtonClick = function(){
      alert("test");
    }
  }])
</script>
```

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="myController">
    {{ name }}
    <button ng-click="onMyButtonClick">test</button>
</div>
```

When I click, nothing happens.

Comment: angular functions must be created before rendering the body. Add script in your head tag

Comment: That doesn't work too :/

Answer (score 4):

Try: `<body ng-app>` ==> `<body ng-app="MyApp">`

In your script:

```
angular.module('MyApp', [])
.controller('myController', ["$scope",function($scope){
    $scope.name = "toto"
}])
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't forget to

- Declare your angular application `angular.module('MyApp', [])`
- Insert the correct attribute in your body `<body ng-app="MyApp">`
- Don't forget parenthesis `ng-click="onMyButtonClick()`

Try this

```js
    var myApp = angular.module('MyApp', []);

    myApp.controller('myController', ["$scope",function($scope){
        $scope.name = 'toto';

        $scope.onMyButtonClick = function(){
            alert("test");
        }
    }])
```

```html
<body ng-app="MyApp">
<h1>Add user</h1>
<form action="addUser" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="pseudo" placeholder="pseudo">
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password">
    <input type="submit" value="envoyer">
</form>
{{1 + 2}}

<div ng-controller="myController">
        {{ name }}
        <button ng-click="onMyButtonClick()">test</button>
    </div>
<a href="./remove">supression</a>

</body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
```